# Local name changes every 10 - 20 minutes

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

I have just bought a new MacBook Pro after my previous one died ( mother card seem to had been the problem). In this one like in my previous the computer's local hostname keeps telling me that the *"MacBookPro-BC-617.local" is already in use on this network* and changes the name of my MacBookPro-BC to *658.local*.

This takes place every day and almost every 10 - 20 minutes. I'm using Mountain Lion. What could be causing this and how could I get rid of it?

Comment: Where is this happening? At work? At home? Do you have other macbooks on the same network?  A little more details about the network please.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me at work when we were using individual wireless access points, each acting as a DHCP server: the MBP was, at different times, catching its signal from these different access points, depending on the location and the strength of the various signals. We changed to use a central DHCP server, and set the access points to extend an existing network, and it solved this problem, as well as a similar issue where the user would get messages that the IP address was already in use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This happens at work but we do not use wifi (due to work requirements). We have a DHCP server, each PC/ laptop has a fix IP address... but now that you mentioned it, the problem could be that also my wifi is on... I have disconnect the wifi, cross fingers this will work. THANKS!